# Calculating the Centroid of polygon in modelbuilder (VBA to Python)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, modelbuilder, vba

Got an easy one, that's got me stuck.
I'm moving some models that were created in 9.3.1 to work in 10.

Part of the model is calculating the X coordinate of a polygon to a specified field.

The code that works (in 9.3.1) is

```
Dim Output As Double
Dim pArea As IArea
Set pArea = [Shape]
Output = pArea.Centroid.X

Expression = output
```

It doesnt work in 10 as i get the following error.

```
General error executing calculator.
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Expected end of statement
Failed to execute (Calculate Field X_COORD).
```

I've tried the following using the python parser

```
def calc(shape,x):
    x = "shape.CENTROID!.split()[0]
    return x

calc(!SHAPE!, !X_COORD! )
```

But that gives an error - invalid syntax on line 2.

Any pointers?
Thanks

Comment: you are missing an end quote on your second line